# Why does C# leave unclosed tags in XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have an XDocument which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<notebook>
    <note>
        <person>
            <surname>Che Guevara</surname>
            <name>Ernesto</name>
            <birthdate>1926</birthdate>
            <telephones>
                <telephone>79626195740</telephone>
            </telephones>
        </person>
    </note>
    <note>
        <person>
            <surname>Castro</surname>
            <name>Fidel</name>
            <birthdate>1926</birthdate>
            <telephones>
                <telephone>79626195740</telephone>
                <telephone>79636296751</telephone>
            </telephones>
        </person>
    </note>
</notebook>
```

And I need to remove all nodes "note", so I use

```
xd.Element("notebook").Elements("note").Remove();
```

I can't figure out why this method leaves my .xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notebook />
```

Why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: `<notebook />` is equal to `<notebook></notebook>`

Comment: It's not an unclosed tag; it's a self-closed tag. If you don't want a self-closed tag, use a schema to tell .NET it's not a self-closing tag, or use the technique outlined in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works properly, the `notebook` element you are referring to is called "self-closing element".
While using XDocument, `<notebook />` means the same as `<notebook></notebook>`, but this could cause issues with other XML parsers, of which some may not recognize `<notebook />`.
Probably XDocument generates self-closing elements, because they are much smaller and thus saving space.

Comment: It's not "equal" in terms of XML, however, since the definition (schema or doctype) controls whether it is self-closing or not. Just a heads up that depending on that definition, a conforming parser could reject `<notebook />` while accepting `<notebook></notebook>`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I was puzzled with my task. I done it with your help. Thank you for quick answer!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Citation for that? I don't remember that with an XSD you can make it... Because I see a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941809/613130) in SO that says the opposite

Comment: Well, it's correct that XSD does not formally have a way of defining an empty element vs. a self-closing one, but there are quirks in a lot of the parsers. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232009/215552). DTDs can influence whether an element is self-closing or not. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50139008/215552) on that same question. Now, that question is specific to PHP's XML (HTML?) parser, but I expect other parsers have similar quirks. Hence my comment.